# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.lint.client.api.Vendor

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Good friends, I am having problems trying to compile the project in android studio, it is 100% in kotlin and when trying to clone it from github and compile it generates the following error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com. android.tools.lint.client.api.Vendor` which I was investigating and I have not found an answer that gives me a solution, could someone help me with this?

It should be noted that the project has different variants as shown in the image, this error appears when trying to compile in the different variants

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Can you add this(if not already)

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions { 
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

in `android/app/build.gradle` file.

Comment: And this go inside the android tag ;-)